# Dumbbell for arms with different strenght

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, biceps, curls

I had bone fracture in my right arm couple of years ago and it is not same in strength as left one. While doing exercise like bicep curl I find while I can take 10kg on left I can take only 7.5 on right. Is it okay to do different weight on two sides or I should keep pushing right arm for same weights?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend working with whatever weight and rep thresholds the weaker arm can manage.  Doing different workouts for each will only increase the disparity between the two.  Eventually, the weaker one will catch up.

Since you body doesn't just work only that specific muscle, in isolation, in normal, non-dumbbell functioning, I'd think an imbalance between sides of the body could lead to other, unforeseen problems, but maybe I'm paranoid about that because I had a bit of scoliosis, as a youth, in part to an imbalance between development between the two sides.

Again, there may not be a detriment, but my own bias is towards relatively equal balance, when possible.